# Needed: Simple HTTP reverse proxy for Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, http, reverse-proxy

I need a **simple** HTTP reverse proxy to be installed on Windows Server 2008 x86 32.

All I need from it is to route incoming HTTP (GET and POST) requests to another machine, with a different port, and url rewriting. For instance, the request (http://) aaa.mydomain.com will be routed to (http://) 10.1.2.3:6789/kuku/aaa/foo. No SSL, no authentication, not even cookies.

That's it! And why, oh why, am I so frustrated about it? Because I tried MS ISA server (on a Windows Server 2003, which is not my exact need), and it's like killing a fly with a machine gun. I know I can program the darn thing, but I prefer using a robust product with simple installation and configuration.

I'm about to try Squid, but I think that it's not that simple when it comes to installation.

Help, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Apache 2.2 and read about mod_proxy. It was pretty straightforward for my needs, and worked better (out of the box).

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you, but I assumed you were looking to use IIS7 based on the fact that you'd tried ISA.

Comment: @aharden, I tried what you suggested. It doesn't work out-of-the box: I couldn't see any icon inside the "Server Farm" page.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the solution [spelled out on Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NewModulesForIIS7ApplicationRequestRoutingProxyAndLoadBalancingModule.aspx).  Combine the IIS7 URL Rewrite Module with Application Request Routing [as described on the IIS forums](http://forums.iis.net/t/1156458.aspx).

[URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)

[Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/extensions/ApplicationRequestRouting)

Answer (score 2):

I guess "Microsoft Application Request Routing" v 2 or the earlier version 1 is more or less your only choice... At least, I don't know of any other Windows based HTTP reverse proxies or load balancers.
[See iis.net for the free Microsoft ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1834) and find the other versions / CPU archs on iis.net too.

Of course there are plenty of Unix based software load balancers and load balancing appliances if you want to go that way, see my answer to ["Software HTTP load balancer?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/433/software-http-load-balancer/9236#9236) for more information.