# Internal website and DNS config

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, web, windows-sbs-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Needed: Simple HTTP reverse proxy for Windows 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/49794/needed-simple-http-reverse-proxy-for-windows-2008)

We have two servers sbs2003 and a new server2008(web server). 
Currently we have remote.example.com pointing to our sbs2003 server fine.
But we need to add in newsite.example.com to point to our new webserver and not the sbs2003.
How do we make this work with only 1 external IP?

Edit: Has to be IIS

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that it has to be IIS.

Comment: Editted :) <!--MinLength -->

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a reverse proxy on the machine that get hits first. I don't think there is an MS solution for this, so you will probably need to go with Apache.

If you really want to use IIS, you should use IIS7+ with ARR module installed.
You can read all about it here: [Using the Application Request Routing Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/489/using-the-application-request-routing-module/)

Also, see this: [Needed: Simple HTTP reverse proxy for Windows 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/49794/needed-simple-http-reverse-proxy-for-windows-2008)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is put an Apache with Mod_Proxy on sbs2003 or move the IP to an actual load balancer (any of the modern ones can do this very simply) in front of this - I think you will save yourself a lot of hassle in the long run - this list of sites will probably grow over time.

However, if it absolutely has to be IIS and IIS only then you should have a look at [ARR](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) (if you have IIS 7+).  If you are on IIS 6 you might have a look at [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/), which now functions as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Just saw that Bart updated his answer with ARR already, didn't have it when I started writing my answer :)