# Looking for a loadbalancer

Tags: linux, load-balancing, dynamic, lvs, round-robin

I am looking for an open source loadbalancer for linux. My requirements are simple. I want One load balancer infront of multiple webservers. It should be able to split the load evenly among the webserver using a round robin fashion. Easy to install and simple to use. Moreover I want to add webservers dynamically(on the go) to the loadbalancer without the need to stop/restart the loadbalancer.

Thanks for your help.

-Sethu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software http load balancer?](http://serverfault.com/questions/433/software-http-load-balancer)

Comment: I tried various load balancers like Balance, Distributor, Apache's mod_proxy_balancer. I have a client program that creates nearly 100 threads that tries to ping the WS ( in this case through a loadbalancer). In all the load balancers I tried, after a minute i get connection time out error. In the apache error log I found : do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: unable to send;errno = Operation not permitted . I still dont understand what it means and how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your views, I used Apache's mod_proxy_balancer and it works, but at times i get 503 error and in the logs i find all servers are in error state. Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) will do this as well.

I have setup [Keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) for various clients. It automates all the [IPVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/ipvs.html) stuff.

Comment: I usually pair the two together, on two (or more) machines. Haproxy for layer 7 load balancing, and keepalived for high availability.

Comment: can u brief me a little more please

Comment: @sethu - what do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know how to dynamically add nodes to the haproxy for loadbalancing.

Comment: @sethu: As far as I know, you can only add new nodes by editting the haproxy config file, then send appropriate signal to haproxy to reload it.

Comment: @Wim I am getting cannot assign requested address at the client side. Any idea what causes this error or how to fix it ?

Comment: @sethu - can you provide the full error message and your config?

Comment: Sure, This is the error message : http://serverfault.com/questions/309083/issue-with-load-balancer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at LVS (ipvs) [LinuxVirtualServer](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) I'm using it for load-balancing a proxy cluster. It has both simple round-robin and more complicated balancing policies.

Comment: Will I be able to add nodes dynamically to it ?

Comment: @sethu, you need to tell the load balancer (LVS) the name and port you want to use on your webservers.  You could pre-configure a bunch that don't yet exist.  If then you added them by starting web services up there, the load balancer could pick them up and start sending work to them.

Comment: @sethu, Of course, it is possible. Moreover, LVS is able to load balance any TCP or even UDP service. Dynamical balancing (according to worker hosts availability) can be made with "ldirectord" monitoring daemon.

Comment: I tried the installation of LVS. But It seems we have to compile it with the kernel. Is it possible to install it as a tool and use it. The installation looks a bit complicated. Or have I understood it the wrong way?

Comment: LVS needs a kernel module, but doesn't you Linux distro has it compiled?

Comment: That was probably very old documentation @sethu.

Comment: I was looking at this documentation : http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/

Comment: I was using these (select you variant ):  http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-NAT.html  http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-IPTunneling.html  http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html   As for me, I used ip-tunneling variant because my worker-nodes are in different network segments.

Comment: If you want some more advanced settings or want to change the load depending on the reaction time of your webservers have a look at lvs-kiss. That`s a daemon written in perl an will change your ipvsadm setup autmatically. The syntax of the configuration file resembles httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx allows you to change the configuration on the fly. See the section "Loading a New Configuration Using Signals" [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxCommandLine)

Comment: cool didn't know Nginx could do that

Answer (score -1):

Would a simple [DNS load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) work for you?

Comment: DNS roundrobin is a poor choice for load balancing, and definitely doesn't fit the OP's requirement for dynamically configuring services.

Comment: The only thing mentioned is load balance via Round Robin and to add webservers...not services and even less in a dynamic way. Sorry to say but I don't think my suggestion deserved a -1...

Comment: there's a difference between balancing a webserver(a service) and a physical webserver, and DNS can't make that distinction. He *does* day that he wanted to add servers dynamically (with a "load balancer", and "on the go"), which you can't do easily with DNS due to multiple layers of caching, and keeping reasonable TTL's for the records. Finally, DNS roundrobin is a poor load-balancing solution in and of itself.

Comment: DNS roundrobin can also break some applications on recent browsers (I've caught chrome and safari doing this), because they'll cache all IP address for a host, and rotate them internally, sending subsequent requests to each server. Webapps often rely on some state through a series of redirects, and this is broken when the dns changes during the chain of requests.