# Suggestions for HTTP load balancers for linux?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software http load balancer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/433/software-http-load-balancer)

Came across few load balancers like Pound(http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) , HAProxy (http://haproxy.1wt.eu) and BalanceNG (http://www.inlab.de/balanceng/index.html).

Any suggestions on choosing a good load-balancer ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are particularly looking to load-balance http traffic, then an http-specific load balance (like Pound) is going to be more flexible than a generic TCP load balance (like ipvs, or balanceng).  An http load balance can make decisions based on http headers, which can be particularly useful in linking client cookies to a particular backend.

Note that in addition to the products you've listed, Apache can also act as a load balancer.  Additionally, there are a number of tools that can act as a "reverse" caching proxy in front of your web servers; these tools can all perform load balancing and can substantially increase your performance if content can be served from cache.  [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) and [nginx](http://nginx.net/) are both popular choices for this purpose, and Apache can also act as a caching proxy.

Answer (score 0):

We use `ipvs` for linux server load-balancing. It's very lightweight and could balance any tcp based application.